# Spring Boot 3 upgrade error: org.hibernate.annotations.Type missing element value

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, annotations

I recently began work on upgrading a Spring Boot application from 2.2.4.RELEASE to 3.0.0

While I'd like to think I managed to do good work on resolving issues from the upgrade so far, this one has blocked me for quite a while now.

The project builds with no problems, however. when I trigger the test suite I encounter the error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: org.hibernate.annotations.Type missing element value

    Caused by: java.lang.annotation.IncompleteAnnotationException: org.hibernate.annotations.Type missing element value
        at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:86)
```

I don't even have any @Type annotation in the test class, so I'm quite confused.

The above error is produced by all my tests, a sample test that produces the error is the following:

```
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import com.getyourguide.pricingalerts.Application;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class HomeEndpointsTest {
    @Test
    public void testReadiness() throws Exception {
        String response = "Ha";

        assertThat(response, is("Ok"));
    }
```

If either of @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) or @SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class) are removed, the test works as expected. Only when both of them are used the error occurs.

My build.gradle contains the following dependencies

```
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client-gson
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:2.2.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:3.0.5'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.0.5'
    annotationProcessor 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core-jakarta:5.6.15.Final'


    implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'

    implementation group: 'jakarta.xml.bind', name: 'jakarta.xml.bind-api', version: '4.0.0'
    implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '4.0.1'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '4.0.2'


    // Spring MVC, testing, and devtools
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-transport
    implementation group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-transport-native-epoll', version: '4.1.90.Final', classifier: 'linux-x86_64'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'


    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    // Lombok annotations to reduce boilerplate code
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
    // create MetaModel for jpa specification/
    annotationProcessor 'org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:6.1.7.Final'
    implementation 'io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60:3.3.0'

    // Sentry
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-spring-boot-starter-jakarta:6.16.0'
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-logback:6.16.0'

    // DataDog
    datadogAgent group: 'com.datadoghq', name: 'dd-java-agent', version: '1.10.0'
    implementation group: 'com.datadoghq', name: 'dd-trace-api', version: '1.10.0'
    implementation 'com.datadoghq:java-dogstatsd-client:4.2.0'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-statsd:1.10.5'
    // Error Prone: (java error/antipattern checker - works with the net.ltgt.errorprone plugin above)
    errorprone 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_core:2.18.0'
    // Database support
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    testImplementation 'net.ttddyy:datasource-proxy:1.8'
    // MySQL
    implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.1.2'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2:2.1.214'
    testImplementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.32'
    // Google sheets
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev20230227-2.0.0'
    //s3
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-s3', version: '1.12.429'
    //thymeleaf
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    //testing
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.2.0'
}
```

I've tried downgrading to SB 2.7 in case it was a change introduced later, but that produced a slew of other problems so I reverted.

I've checked that It's running with  Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final, which should be compatible with io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60:3.0.1.

I've tried removing some annotations, (see above) to understand if a specific annotation triggers the error, but since it's only when two of the annotations are used at the same time, I'm unsure.

I've tried finding similar questions on slack, but none seemed quite right.

If anyone has an idea for how to resolve the error, or if I've missed some piece of documentation on how to properly upgrade things I'd really appreciate the support.

Best,
Victor

Answer (score 0):

Check your entity class for any instances where you are using
@Type annotation, replace with @JdbcTypeCode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you add a format to your shared code ?